# How do you resolve 'Already defined in this MetaData Instance' Error with Flask Pytest, SqlAlchemy, and Flask Sessions?

Tags: session, flask, sqlalchemy, pytest

I'm having an issue with SQLAlchemy, Flask (specifically testing with pytest), and the Flask Sessions library.

When I try to set up a basic testing client, I get the following warnings + errors that prevent all tests from working:

```
SAWarning: This declarative base already contains a class with the same class name and module name as flask_session.sessions.Session, and will be replaced in the string-lookup table.
```

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'sessions' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.
```

Based on the research I've done, if I made this sessions model myself, I would just try adding extend_existing to it and that might fix the problem, but it's not in any of the models I created, so I'm unsure how to resolve this.

Any advice would be appreciated! Thank you.

****init**.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask
from flask import session
from flask_session import Session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# Initialize database object
db=SQLAlchemy()
sess = Session()

def create_app(test=False):
    """Construct the core application."""
    app = Flask(__name__)
    if test:
        app.config.from_object('config.TestConfig')
    else:
        app.config.from_object('config.Config')
    
    # Configure db connection, initialize sessions
    db.app = app
    db.init_app(app)
    app.config['SESSION_SQLALCHEMY'] = db

    sess.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        from . import routes  # Import routes
        db.create_all()  # Create database tables for our data models

        return app
```

**test_basic.py**

```
import os, sys
# sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
# import main
import os
import tempfile
import flask
import pytest
from err_app import create_app,create_app_test, db, sess

import err_app
from flask_session import Session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def test_client():
    # flask_app = create_app_test()
    flask_app = create_app(test=True)
 
    # Establish an application context before running the tests.
    ctx = flask_app.app_context()
    ctx.push()
    if flask_app.config['TESTING'] == True:
        print("EMPTYING AND RE CREATING DATABASE")
        db.drop_all()
        from err_app.models import ErrorModel, ErrorParameterModel, TemplatesModel, UsersModel
        db.create_all()
        # sess.init_app(flask_app)
    # flask_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'test.db')
 
    # Flask provides a way to test your application by exposing the Werkzeug test Client
    # and handling the context locals for you.
    testing_client = flask_app.test_client()

 
    yield testing_client  # this is where the testing happens!
 
    ctx.pop()

def test_create_app():
  app = create_app(test=True)
  assert app
  assert app.config['TESTING'] == True

def test_home_page(test_client):
    
    """
    GIVEN a Flask application
    WHEN the '/' page is requested (GET)
    THEN check the response is valid
    """
    
    response = test_client.get('/calculate_bounds')
    print(response)
    # print(response.text)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

**Models**

```
from . import db
# from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
# db=SQLAlchemy()

class ErrorModel(db.Model):
    """Data model for ErrorModel accounts."""

    __tablename__ = 'err-models-table'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                   primary_key=True)

    model_name = db.Column(db.Text,
                    index=False,
                    unique=False,
                    nullable=False)

    model_zip_attachment = db.Column(db.LargeBinary,
                                      index=False,
                                      unique=False,
                                      nullable=False)
    model_csv = db.Column(db.LargeBinary,
                            index=False,
                            unique = False,
                            nullable = False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime,
                            index=False,
                            unique=False,
                            nullable=False)

    model_version= db.Column(db.Text,
                              index=False,
                              unique=False,
                              nullable=False)

    app_version= db.Column(db.Text,
                            index=False,
                            unique=False,
                            nullable=False)

    notes = db.Column(db.Text,
                        index=False,
                        unique=False,
                        nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<ErrorModel {}>'.format(self.model_name)

class ErrorParameterModel(db.Model):
    """Data model for ErrorModel accounts."""

    __tablename__ = 'err-parameters'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                   primary_key=True)

    error_description = db.Column(db.Text,
                    index=False,
                    unique=False,
                    nullable=False)

    error_label = db.Column(db.Text,
                    index=False,
                    unique=False,
                    nullable=False)
    template_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("templates.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
    
    block_description = db.Column(db.Text,
                    index=False,
                    unique=False,
                    nullable=False)
    block_labels = db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.Text),
                    index=False,
                    unique=False,
                    nullable=False)
    input_type = db.Column(db.Text,
                    index=False,
                    unique=False,
                    nullable=False)
    uncorr_determ = db.Column(db.Text,
                    index=False,
                    unique=False,
                    nullable=False)

    value = db.Column(db.Text,
                    index=False,
                    unique=False,
                    nullable=False)

    unit = db.Column(db.Text,
                    index=False,
                    unique=False,
                    nullable=True)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime,
                            index=False,
                            unique=False,
                            nullable=False)

    notes = db.Column(db.Text,
                        index=False,
                        unique=False,
                        nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<ErrorModel {}>'.format(self.error_description)

class TemplatesModel(db.Model):
    """Data model for ErrorModel accounts."""

    __tablename__ = 'templates'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                   primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.Text,
                    index=False,
                    unique=False,
                    nullable=False)

    user_id= db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("users.id"))
    
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime,
                            index=False,
                            unique=False,
                            nullable=False)
    project = db.Column(db.Text,
                        index=False,
                        unique=False,
                        nullable=True)
    gauge_hw = db.Column(db.Text,
                        index=False,
                        unique=False,
                        nullable=True)

    error_model_version = db.Column(db.Text,
                        index=False,
                        unique=False,
                        nullable=True)
    model_number = db.Column(db.Text,
                        index=False,
                        unique=False,
                        nullable=True)
    num_sigmas = db.Column(db.Text,
                        index=False,
                        unique=False,
                        nullable=True)
    
    notes = db.Column(db.Text,
                        index=False,
                        unique=False,
                        nullable=True)

    children = db.relationship('ErrorParameterModel', cascade='all,delete', backref='templates')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Table {}>'.format(self.name)

class UsersModel(db.Model):
    """Data model for ErrorModel accounts."""

    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                 primary_key=True)

    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime,
                            index=False,
                            unique=False,
                            nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a flaw in Flask-Session which was fixed in an unmerged pull request:

https://github.com/fengsp/flask-session/blob/1c1f7903184673682bd1d75432c8f455b62393a4/flask_session/sessions.py

The main part of the fix is the line `if table not in self.db.metadata:`

However, because the pull request is so old, it has slight differences from the newest version. But the fix itself still works if you subclass the SqlAlchemySessionInterface. Here's an example of a currently working fix in my own Flask project: https://github.com/tassaron/muffin-shop/blob/main/src/helpers/main/session_interface.py

Comment: Issue seems to be fixed in flask-session as of 0.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Following [What is the use of **table_args** = {'extend_existing': True} in SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57646511/what-is-the-use-of-table-args-extend-existing-true-in-sqlalchemy), you need to add `__table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}` to the relationship patterns if you want to allow a table in your ORM to get changed.

See [Basic Relationship Patterns](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#basic-relationship-patterns)

For a one-to-one relationship:

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    __tablename__ = "my_table1"
    my_id_of_table1 = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Child(Base):
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    __tablename__ = "my_table2"
    my_id_of_table2 = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Thus, in Flask, put `__table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}` in the classes and then check any changes in the error. You might have to run the ORM code from scratch again to get rid of settings in memory.